# preg_replace: как убрать из тега лишние атрибуты?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте. Возможно ли в тексте почистить тег img, да так что бы стало `<img src="путь до картинки">`, т.е. необходимо вырезать лишние `class, style, width`... и т.д.

```
<img class="wp-image-4308 alignleft" width="250" height="123" alt="Как научить ребенка читать по слогам" src="http://delfin4ik.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/kak-nauchit-rebenka-chitat-po-slogam-300x153.png" title="Как научить ребенка читать по слогам" style="margin-left: -5px; margin-right: 10px;">
```

Comment: я думаю, тут проще (и логичней), добыть src из img, а потом просто
"<img src='$src'>"

Answer (score 7):

Вот где-то так

```
$ext = preg_replace('/<img.*?src="(.*?)".*?>/im','<img src="$1" />',$src);
```

Comment: Вот спасибо, вот помог!

Comment: Для большей надежности лучше изменить поисковую регулярку на `/<img[^>]*src="([^"]*)"[^>]*>/ims`  иначе могут быть проблемы с жадностью и захватить|изменить лишнее.
@binliz , спасибо за $1 не знал, что так можно.

Comment: @kingNothing, выражение в ответе спотыкнется если увидит нечто вроде  

    <img /><img src="..." />
на правильных примерах все будет ок.  
По скорости Ваш вариант отработает быстрее.  
P.S. Для выделения куска кода можно использовать  

    `некий код`
тогда символы не будут съедаться.

Comment: @kingNothing не за что с номерами очень удобно, про жадность я и не сомневался я даже и не проверял регулярку просто отписал по вопросу свое мнение.